# What kind of conversion efforts are there involved in porting a complete droid app to work on Blackberry?

Tags: android, blackberry, import

I have a simple app I coded  for android that I want to go on Blackberry too - How easy is it to get the code over to their SDK and run it working as intended?

I was only wondering if anyone knew from experience.  The only API's on Droid I really use are camera and face detect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its another animal, the UI works completly diferently, imo, the blackberry SDK is far more limited and harder to program for, especially if you want to support OS4.5.

You will also find yourself rethinking the logic behind the app, mainly because of screen real estate and to make the app feel like it belongs on a blackberry. This is key to make the user happy, user want apps to look and feel like the phone they are using.

There are some other diferences in what java code is supported, for example, blackberry has no Regex support, where android does.

You will be able to reuse some code, but not all.

Comment: Not to mention that Android is all touchscreen whereas with BlackBerry you will need to support trackball-only devices which means thinking about UI focus, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The two platforms are completely distinct from each other, save the fact that they are both using Java. This fact does help some if you are careful to avoid having your UI tied to any of your application logic/specifics (a Model-View-Controller structure would be very useful in attempting to support both platforms).

Also, BlackBerry's Java is based on J2ME, which means that it is based on an older flavor of Java; more specifically, Java 1.3. Avoid using any language constructs that were introduced to Java after 1.3 as this will further complicate supporting both platforms.